# Convert MKMapRect to CGRect

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkmaprect

I'm trying to find out the size of an MKMapRect in points (i.e. 320x568 points for iPhone).

Is there something similar to converting co-ordinates to points? i.e.

```
[self.mapView convertCoordinate:coordinate1 toPointToView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map view has the [`convertRegion:toRectToView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW9) method which takes an `MKCoordinateRegion` and converts it to a `CGRect` relative to the specified view.

If you have an `MKMapRect`, first convert it to an `MKCoordinateRegion` using the `MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect` function and then call `convertRegion:toRectToView:`.

Example:

```
MKCoordinateRegion mkcr = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(someMKMapRect);

CGRect cgr = [mapView convertRegion:mkcr toRectToView:self.view];
```

Remember that although the `MKMapRect` for some fixed area will not change as the map is zoomed or panned, the corresponding `CGRect` *will* vary in its `origin` and `size`.